# display random web page

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering is it possible to display random page each time I refresh my url addres.
I have my local network. Inside, lets say I have address base.lan and few other pages like: page1.lan, page2.lan, page3.lan
So every time I enter or refresh base.lan page I would like to see one of that other pages.
I also added js code which refresh page every few mins (to auto change content)

For the static page I could use:

```
<iframe src='page1.lan/index.html'><\/iframe>
```

but I need to display that pages randomly (page1, page2 or page3). And the page should looks natural.
I also was thinking about reverse proxy but I don't know how to display random page and what happened when I reload that page? even tho I have to add refresh script on each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Url= [
    'page1.lan',
    'page2.lan',
    'page3.lan'
];

var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * Url.length);
var html='<div class="span4"><iframe src=" '+ Url[index] + '/index.html"></iframe></div>';
document.write(html);
```

**OR**

use a jquery to dynamically add the src attribute into the iframe

```
 $("#myiframe").get(0).contentWindow.location.href = '+Url[index]+';
```

Comment: Ok I solved my problem thx to your previous answer. But I think I should mark this one as a "best answer" At least it looks more like what I have now ;)

Answer (score 2):

IF you are using c# I can help you with this solution.

1. Create an instance of Random class somewhere. Note that it's pretty important not to create a new instance each time you need a
   random    number. You should reuse the old instance to achieve
   uniformity in    the generated numbers. You can have a static field
   somewhere:

   `static Random rnd = new Random();`
2. Assuming you already have a record or list of random pages to be
   displayed. say.

   `var RandomUrl= new List<string> { "page1.lan/index.html","page2.lan/index.html", "page3.lan/index.html" };`
3. Write this method in your program.

   ```
    public string RandomUrlGenerator()
    {

     //Ask for random number from total list count in your RandomUrl list       
     int r = rnd.Next(RandomUrl.Count);
     return RandomUrl[r];
    }
   ```
4. write this in <**Iframe**>

`<iframe src="@Url.Action("RandomUrlGenerator")"><\/iframe>`

Comment: @s1c I have not tried this solution. And I have provided solution If you are using c# and Razor Syntax in your cshtml file.

Comment: Reading the code it makes sense. Unfortunately I don't know much about Razor and handling c# in html. Now I have to find out how to move it to the js for example.

Comment: If the code makes sense you are good to implement in what ever language you are good in. In a breif 
1. create a method that would return random url as I have specified above
2. call the particular method from your html tag using the action name in the <iframe src="****">

Comment: Ok I solved my problem thx to you ;) I've create array with my webpages. var RandomUrl=new Array() and inside RandomUrl[0]="page1.lan" ... etc. Then Math.random() to display ;)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you could create an array of the available pages then, at [parent] page load, grab a random page from the array and apply it as 'src' of the iFrame . . .